# Pooling Survreg Results Across Multiply Imputed Datasets - Error Message: log(1 - 2 * pnorm(width/2)) : NaNs produced

Tags: r, survival-analysis, imputation, r-mice, survival

I am trying to run an interval regression using the survival r package (as described here https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/interval-regression/), but I am running into difficulties when trying to pool results across multiply imputed datasets. Specifically, although estimates are returned, I get the following error: log(1 - 2 * pnorm(width/2)) : NaNs produced. The estimates seem reasonable, at face value (no NaNs, very large or small SEs).

I ran the same model on the stacked dataset (ignoring imputations) and on individual imputed datasets, but in either case, I do not get the error. Would someone be able to explain to me what is going on? Is this an ignorable error? If not, is there a workaround that avoids this error?

Thanks so much!

```
# A Reproducible Example

require(survival)
require(mice)
require(car)

# Create DF
dat <- data.frame(dv = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 0, NA, 1, 4, NA, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 4, NA, 2, 4),
                  catvar1 = factor(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
                  catvar2 = factor(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0)))

dat_imp <- mice(data = dat)

# Transform Outcome Var for Interval Reg
dat_imp_long <- complete(dat_imp, action = "long", include=TRUE)

# 1-4 correspond to ranges (e.g., 1 = 1 to 2 times...4 = 10 or more)
# create variables that reflect this range
dat_imp_long$dv_low <- car::recode(dat_imp_long$dv, "0 = 0; 1 = 1; 2 = 3; 3 = 6; 4 = 10")
dat_imp_long$dv_high <- car::recode(dat_imp_long$dv, "0 = 0; 1 = 2; 2 = 5; 3 = 9; 4 = 999")
dat_imp_long$dv_high[dat_imp_long$dv_high > 40] <- Inf

# Convert back to mids
dat_mids <- as.mids(dat_imp_long)

# Run Interval Reg 
model1 <- with(dat_mids, survreg(Surv(dv_low, dv_high, type = "interval2") ~ 
                                     catvar1 + catvar2, dist = "gaussian"))

# Warning message for both calls: In log(1 - 2 * pnorm(width/2)) : NaNs produced
# Problem does not only occur with pool, but summary
summary(model1)
summary(pool(model1))

# Run Equivalent Model on Individual Datasets
# No errors produced
imp1 <- subset(dat_imp_long, .imp == 1)
model2 <- survreg(Surv(dv_low, dv_high, type = "interval2") ~ 
                       catvar1 + catvar2, dist = "gaussian", data = imp1)
summary(model2)

imp2 <- subset(dat_imp_long, .imp == 2)
model3 <- survreg(Surv(dv_low, dv_high, type = "interval2") ~ 
                    catvar1 + catvar2, dist = "gaussian", data = imp2)
summary(model3)

# Equivalent Analysis on Stacked Dataset
# No error
model <- with(dat_imp_long, survreg(Surv(dv_low, dv_high, type = "interval2") ~ 
                                  catvar1 + catvar2, dist = "gaussian"))
summary(model)
```

Comment: I only get a warning with your code, not an error. I wonder if this question might be more appropriate on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as this doesn't seem to be an issue with programming. It looks like there's an issue calculating the deviance when pooling, but I'm not familiar with interval regression to know why.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right, it's a warning not an error. I can post it on Cross Validated, if it would be more appropriate there

Comment: I think you're more likely to receive a response there as I don't immediately see anything wrong with the programming (although as I noted I am not very familiar with interval regression)